# Keeping text perfectly aligned with the form for printing

Tags: vb.net, printing

So I've inherited some source code with a task to fix an existing problem. I'm not really sure where to begin, and I'm hoping someone else has already experienced this particular issue.

So in vb.net I have a form. The background of the form is an image of a physical document. This specific set of functions are essentially retrieving information from a database, Throwing it into labels. And lining the labels up with the various fields on this form.

The fields are the only thing being printed here. But no two printers print the same way. And so all the labels aren't lining up. Even if the print preview shows it correct, The printer will print it misaligned.

I've done some research into hard margins and how to compensate for them, but I'm not sure if that's the answer or not. I spent all day yesterday trying to find a solution, but this particular issue has me stumped.

What I'm interested in is a conceptual answer.

I can't just put the image up, fill it out and print the whole thing. The form is already made and loaded into the printer, the only thing these methods should be doing is printing the text onto the form. But the process needs to stay lined up, regardless of the printer being used. (it has to compensate for all types of printers) since you can't tell a user that they have to use this specific model of printer with the application.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Why not create a report using ReportViewer (if you have VS professional) and print the report instead of printing a form? It's easier to manage printing with a report.

Comment: What about the fact that it's printing onto a physical form. And that I need it to line up perfectly. will a report compensate margins and all of that? (I've never dealt with printing before)

Comment: You can specify the margins on your report. You can also deal with the font size, bold, etc. I use it to print AutoCAD drawings and other various reports for the management department.

Comment: Ah, I only have premium on the workstation I'm using here. and I do not believe i have access to a professional copy of VS.

Comment: my only concern is lining up everything to be perfect. The method fills out a pre-printed document. and just using it in the office you can see the differences. this stuff was all pre existing. It's also an older project, it uses devx tools. and i believe the who thing is already an XtraReport.

Comment: Is this a tractor feed printer or a page printer(i.e. Laser or Ink Jet)

Comment: that's my main problem, It needs to be printer in specific. So I need to be able to support both. I'm aware that both of those types have different hard margins, which could explain part of the problem.

Comment: What type of pre printed forms are you using Continuous or individual sheets

Comment: individual. Specifically HCFA 1500's

Comment: You have two different ways of adjusting the print, on a dot matrix continuous form printer you adjust the printer to the form by moving the tractors and adjusting the TOF. for a page printer you will need to adjust the printing by shifting(adjusting) the margins. as Alex stated it would be easier to print the **entire** form, that way you do not have to worry about alignment. Most programs have a alignment function that prints out the fields to check alignment, you could then make adjustments from there.  I am sorry if this is a little vague.

Comment: Now, just for clarification, are you talking of printing the whole form onto a blank piece of paper. Or are you talking of printing the whole form onto the pre printed document that I already have. Because just flat printing the form won't work for this case specifically.

Comment: When I mentioned the entire form, I was meaning printing on a blank page (I do understand why that may not be an option), the other options were talking about printing on your preprinted forms.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the input. I'll look into margin setup and see what I can do with that.

Comment: A little old and maybe you don't need this but how bout using something like `iTextSharp` and using pdf to print. It will provide you will cross printer support without changes in layout.